# Gyroscope driven sphero

Tags: ios, iphone, sphero-api, sphero

I'm working on sphero app and want to add a gysorcope based driving. As far as I understand I need to create `CMMotionManager`, get the `yaw` value and pass it as a parameter to instance of `RKTiltDriveAlgorithm`. What I don't understand is where do I pass the `RKTiltDriveAlgorithm` instance. Documentation says to pass the instance to `RKRobotControl` which doesn't seem to be accessible from anywhere. `RKRobotProvider` has a property for `RKRobotControl` but it's not assignable. Here's my code so far

```
RKTiltDriveAlgorithm *tilt = [[RKTiltDriveAlgorithm alloc] initWithOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation];
...
[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
    float yaw = (180/M_PI) * motion.attitude.yaw;
    tilt.orientationAngle = yaw;
}];
```

Would appreciate some hints, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I am quite sorry for the confusion regarding this.  We have actually been streamlining the Tilt Controls to make integration easier.  Please see the RobotUISample [https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-iOS-SDK/tree/master/samples/RobotUISample] for an example of how the new system is being used.

In short, we moved Tilt under the hood of RKDriveControl [https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-iOS-SDK/blob/master/frameworks/RobotKit.framework/Headers/RKDriveControl.h], which is a singleton.  Now, you just create and use this singleton instance to drive the Sphero.  We even tap directly into the CMMotionManager for you now.  All that you need to provide is the Drive Type and tell it to start driving.

```
/*Call when Robot is connected*/
- (void)startDriving {    
    //Drive with Tilt
    [[RKDriveControl sharedDriveControl] startDriving:RKDriveControlTilt];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Still doesn't seem to work for me. I replaced `RKDriveControlJoyStick` with `RKDriveControlTilt` in sample app, yet sphero doesn't move at all. Am I doing something wrong?